# Calculating the coefficient of variation within pairs

Tags: r, repeated-measures, descriptive-statistics, coefficient-of-variation

I would like to calculate the coefficient of variation of an assay where I measured each sample in duplicate. I have no statistical background but from my understanding I would need the standard variation within pairs of duplicates to do this.

So I have following questions:

1. Is it correct to use the sd within pairs?
2. Is the way I am calculating the sd within pairs correct (see below)?
3. To obtain the CV should I divide the sd within pairs by the overall mean?
4. Does the sd within pairs as I calculated it correspond to the sd within in a random effects model?

```
# function to get sd within pairs
sdwp <- function(y) {
  # sum of squares within
  ssqw <- sum(sapply(y, function(x) diff(x)**2/2))
  # sample standard deviation within
  sqrt(ssqw/(length(y)-1))
}

# example data of results with small sd within, large overall sd
aa <- list(c(10,12),
           c(13,11),
           c(18,17.5))
# example data of results with large sd within, small overall sd
bb <- list(c(14,18),
           c(13,17),
           c(15,17.5))

# wrong sd of assays considering the design
sd(unlist(aa)); sd(unlist(bb))
[1] 3.382553
[1] 2.043282

# actual sd of the assays
sdwp(aa); sdwp(bb)
[1] 1.436141
[1] 3.092329

# wrong cv of assays considering the design
sd(unlist(aa))*100/mean(unlist(aa)); sd(unlist(bb))*100/mean(unlist(bb))
[1] 24.90223
[1] 12.97322

# actual cv of the assays
sdwp(aa)*100/mean(unlist(aa)); sdwp(bb)*100/mean(unlist(bb))
[1] 10.57281
[1] 19.63384
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is not a code-checking service; nor is use of R universal even among people who answer questions. More positively, if I understand correctly using the difference between larger and smaller values and comparing that with their mean seems about as much as is needed or justified here. Using 7 significant figures for summary statistics from data that are small integers or half-integers also seems spurious.

Comment: @NickCox well, I just tried to provide as much information as possible to ask a well received question... Besides, the code aspect is just 1/4 of the points I am interested in. Obvisouly this figures are not how I plan to report the results. And lastly, using the coefficient of variation is a standard way of reporting the repeatability within an assay in biology/medicine - which I am trying to do without introducing bias due to repeated measures.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If your question is primarily statistical that's fine but make sure that is your emphasis too.  I am also familiar with the coefficient of variation and have posted on it here. It's just that with very small samples keeping the analysis direct and simple has extra point. And -- to be frank -- it really is not obvious from your post that you plan to report differently. The only guide we have is what you say.

Comment: The coefficient of variation makes most sense whenever the SD is proportional to the mean, equivalent here to proportionality between difference and mean, which you can plot directly. I have seen CV misapplied when proportionality is lacking, in which case it may obscure quite as much as it clarifies.